# Align the values of a JavaScript map

Tags: javascript, align

Say that you have the following JavaScript map literal

```
{a: 1,
 aoeu: 2}
```

and want the values aligned for readability like

```
{a:    1,
 aoeu: 2}
```

Is this possible to do with emacs? I'm currently using `js2-mode` and `M-x align` does nothing. `M-x align-regexp` can in some cases be used when the values all begin with the same prefix or like in this case when they're all numbers, but I've yet to find a generally applicable regexp.

Comment: Doesn't `C-u M-x align-regexp` with complex align regexp `:\(\s-*\)` and default args otherwise (i.e., 1st group for aligning and 1 space) do exactly that?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Unless I've managed to miscopy your regexp it seems to have the following result: http://paste.debian.net/996677/

Comment: You did miss the prefix arg `C-u` which stands for `Control-u`. Press `Control-u` and afterwards `Meta-x` and input `align-regexp` enter...

Comment: You are so right, thank you. But it is quite the command aint it?

Comment: It would be nice if you could test it with some of your more complicated cases. If it works for you I would write up an answer.

Comment: I've tried on a good set of "wild" maps in my code base and it seems to be working even on map literals where some values depend on the result of an expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`align-regexp` is called non-interactively like that:

`(align-regexp BEG END REGEXP &optional GROUP SPACING REPEAT)`

The argument REGEXP of `align-regexp` is a regexp that should contain at least one group.

For alignment characters are deleted from the back of the substring matching the first group or whitespace is inserted at the back of that substring.

If you call `align-regexp` interactively **without** prefix argument the actual argument REGEXP results from prepending the user-input with the string `\(\s-*\)`. The effect is that space is inserted and deleted **before** the alignment character given in the user-input.

That is not what you want. You actually want `:\(\s-*\)` as REGEXP.

If you call `align-regexp` with prefix argument <kbd>C-u</kbd> you can input all arguments (required and optional) of `align-regexp` literally. (BEG and END as beginning and end position of region).

I suggest you call <kbd>C-u M-x</kbd> `align-regexp` with complex align regexp `:\(\s-*\)` and default args otherwise (i.e., 1st group for aligning and 1 space) to get what you want.